# How do I style or control the elements that are saved from a list/key of an array in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

A. I want to create a 2x3 grid. The grid would be made of a single component containing different information. Each component has an image, image alt, title and description. Again, each component is inside a 2x3 grid.

I was successful in getting each component displaying on top of each other. But I want them to be paired. I have tried using the .map() function to iterate through the list and have successfully gotten a dump of elements. I don't know how to control the components individually as what I was doing is a list dump of elements. I do not know how to use CSS with this as I can't control the

```
<component />
```

It is all a `<div>{webItems}</div>` dump now.

```
// From App.js

    function App() {
      const webItems = webImages.map(item => <WebItem key={item.id} item={item} />);
      return <div>{webItems}</div>;
    }

    // From WebItem.js

    function WebItem(props) {
      return (

            <div className="webItem" key={props.item.id}>
              <img src={props.item.imageURL} alt={props.item.imageAlt} />
              <h3>{props.item.imageTitle}</h3>
              <p>{props.item.imageBlurb}</p>
            </div>

      );
    }

//There is an external file using a webImages variable as an array holding objects of individual, key, imageURL, imageAlt, imageTitle and imageBlurb info.
```

I'm not sure if there's a CSS or a react JS technique to solve this problem. I just want each image and its own description info to be in a 2x3 grid. I also would like to be able to style each one if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that you're stacking 6 `div`s on each other. But you want a grid like structure. One way to do it would be to surround each pair in a `div` and use `display: flex`.

I've written code to group an array into an array of 2, so that it becomes easier when rendering.

```js
const webImages = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
function App() {
  // [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
  const groupedItems = webImages.reduce((groups, item, idx, arr) => {
    if (idx % 2 === 0) {
      groups.push(arr.slice(idx, idx + 2));
    }
    return groups;
  }, []);
  const webItems = groupedItems.map(([item1, item2]) => (
    <div className="row">
      <WebItem key={item1} item={item1} />
      <WebItem key={item2} item={item2} />
    </div>
  ));
  return <div>{webItems}</div>;
}

function WebItem(props) {
  return <div className="webItem">{props.item}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.webItem {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: How do I check for "even" using your code if I was using {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id:3},  {id:4}, {id:5}, {id:6}? These eventually become keys as you may already know. Is there a way to hook into the id # to check for even?

Comment: You could use `item.id` instead of `idx`. But it's better to use `idx` since it actually guarantees that it'll be in order, like 0,1,2...